# How to use a rails helper inside Vue.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2

I've started using Vue with my rails app and I was wondering how I can use my rails helper from within Vue. I think I have to include it as a component.

For example:

movies_helper.rb

```
module MoviesHelper

   def runtime(runtime)
        hours = runtime / 60
        mins  = runtime % 60

        dur = "#{hours}h #{mins}m"
    end

end
```

application.js

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import App from '../app.vue'

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    var movieDiv = document.querySelector("#movies")
    if (movieDiv != undefined) {
        const app = new Vue({
            el: movieDiv,
            data: {
                movies: JSON.parse(movieDiv.dataset.movies)
            },
            template: "<App :original_movies='movies' />",
            components: { App }
        })
    }
});
```

app.vue

```
<template>
    <ul id="app" class="movies">
    <li v-for="movie in original_movies" class="movie card">
        {{ movie }}
    </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: ["original_movies"],
}
```

Comment: You can't use Ruby code inside Vue.js.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. How about a helper without content_tag?

I'll update main post.

Comment: No, again, you cannot run Ruby inside Vue.js. It doesn't matter how much Ruby or what methods you use Ruby is a different language that runs on the server.

Comment: Maybe things are not quite as black and white: It is true that vue is client and rails server. But the asset pipeline handles the js files. I'll write more as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly call your Ruby code from your client-side JavaScript. If it's just that particular helper you're looking to replicate on the client side, it's easy enough to port to JavaScript:

```
const runtime = (runtime) => {
  hours = parseInt(runtime / 60)
  mins = runtime % 60
  return hours + "h " + mins + "m"
}
```

If you're looking more generally to be able to use helpers you have on the Rails side to display data in a certain way, then you could call the helper from within the server-side API call that returns the JSON data in the first place - so for example, you might return a `runtime` attribute in minutes, as well as a `runtime_formatted` attribute that uses your helper to return the `1h 33m` display version too, all within your JSON. Generally those decisions come down to whether you want the client to be in charge of how something is displayed, or whether you want a consistent display format to be driven by the API.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah okay, that again makes sense. I'll just have to start wrapping my head around this concept.

Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, literal answer: difficult, directly not possible.
The more difficult way would be to install [ruby2js](https://github.com/rubys/ruby2js) and convert code.
But since the code is so little, it's really not worth it.

BTW, you know that you can rename the file, add an .erb ending, and then use erb inside the file. This can be handy not only to use existing functionality, but to transfer data (from ruby to vue)

What i tend to do is write the app part for vue in the rails template (with haml actually. And in ruby, with ruby2js). That way you have access to helpers and controller data. But off course only when the template is rendered. But that tends to go a long way.

Actually even components can be created that way by using the x-template syntax. Then you can write template in haml that rails renders into html and vue parses.

I'll try an demonstrate in haml code (ie the rails view that gets rendered (possible as a partial)

```
#movies
  %ul.movies
    %li.movie_card{ "v-for": "movie in movies"}
      {{ movie }}
:javascript
  const app = new Vue({
    el: "#movies",
      data: {
        movies:  "#{@movies.to_json}"
      }
    }
```

Much shorter and much less hassle, imho. (KISS principle)
Notice how the movie data is passed literally, during render, with the to_json (that's ruby because of the #{} ). to_json let's you easily limit attributes (with :only) and if i need more control i use rabl